# ?? Operator in Lambda LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
results = results.Where(x => x.SomeValue ?? 0 == 0);
```

I want to check if a value is null and if is null, make it zero and then make the comparison.

I don't know how to put the extra parenthesis ()

Error message is:

Comment: Just put in more parenthesis than you need and remove them until it stops working.  Simple enough to test.

Comment: If null-coalescing causes you so many problems, why not just check for null? `(x => x == null || x == 0)`? I'd argue that the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 7):

```
results = results.Where(x => (x.SomeValue ?? 0) == 0);
```

---

But I found more readable explicit check for null if you deal with nullable type:

```
results = results.Where(x => !x.SomeValue.HasValue || x.SomeValue == 0);
```

Another option is `GetValueOrDefault()` method, which will return zero for integer (long, byte):

```
results = results.Where(x => x.SomeValue.GetValueOrDefault() == 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
results = results.Where(x => (x.SomeValue ?? 0) == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x.SomeValue` is a nullable int, you can do this:

```
results = results.Where(x => (x.SomeValue ?? 0) == 0);
```

But you can only "replace" the null value with a value of the same type, so if it's a string or something else, this won't work.

You could do this with the inline if operator as well:

```
results = results.Where(x => x.SomeValue == null ? true : x.SomeValue == 0)
```

Comment: Though of course, as Sergey mentioned, readability is key. Neither of these are as readable as explicit comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a nullable int (int?) type for this.

```
results = results.Where(x => (x.SomeValue ?? 0) == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know where to put the parenthesis :D